# What is the purpose of closets?

Tags: nethack

I am having a hard time correlating what I see in the [Wiki](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Closet) and what I'm seeing in the game itself.

According to the wiki...

> Sometimes closets are generated
>   without doors leading to them. The
>   only way to get to these is for a
>   corridor to be generated adjacent to
>   them, or to teleport or dig in. Such
>   closets always have a scroll of
>   teleportation inside, and a potion of
>   object detection will reveal its
>   presence. Every closet has either a
>   door or a scroll of teleportation.

However, I have come across many, many closets, and I have never seen anything inside them.  At one point I teleported to the vault, but that was just on a random pathway.  Am I missing something?

Comment: A closet with a door could be used as a stash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You generally won't come across the closets without doors unless you're using magic mapping or objection detection. Occasionally they actually overlap with a normal corridor, leaving the scroll of teleportation lying in the corridor. I've never seen a vault teleport in a normal corridor but if you've run into one then I suppose it's possible.

There's no particular purpose to empty closets, although they do make a good place to lock yourself in to heal or wait out hallucinations.